# Making instance of Applicative

Tags: haskell, typeclass, applicative

Still not a hundred percent shure how to make instances of the more complex types. Have this:

```
data CouldBe a = Is a | Lost deriving (Show, Ord)
```

Made an instance of `Functor`, using `Maybe` as an example:

```
instance Functor CouldBe where 
  fmap f (Is x) = Is (f x) 
  fmap f Lost   = Lost
```

For doing something like this:

```
tupleCouldBe :: CouldBe a -> CouldBe b -> CouldBe (a,b)
tupleCouldBe x y = (,) <$> x <*> y
```

`CouldBe` needs to be an instance of `Applicative`, but how would you go about that? Sure I can look it up and copy it, but I want to learn the process behind it and finally end up with the `instance` declaration of CouldBe.

Comment: Start by writing down the functions you need to define to make `CouldBe` an instance of `Applicative`, with their type signatures (specialised to `CouldBe`). You should find there's really only one sensible solution if you let the types guide you. And your `Functor` instance shows you how to handle `Lost`.

Comment: Pattern match as much as possible and then construct the results in the only way that type checks. This works often.

Comment: Logically I'd be defining `pure` and `<*>`, correct? I think pure should be simple like `pure a = Is a`, but doesn't `<*>` require more variants...

Comment: Try pattern matching on each side of `<*>`; this should give four different cases. Then use @RobinZigmond's advice and 'follow the types' for each case. One other thing which could help is typed holes: if you don't know what to put somewhere, use an underscore `_`, and GHC will give you the type which should be there. They're _incredibly_ useful in these sort of 'follow the types' situations.

Comment: Note that your `CouldBe` is isomorphic to Haskell's built-in `Maybe` type, so any time you want to know how to write an instance for your type, you can just look how the corresponding instance for `Maybe` is written.

Comment: @JosephSible it is indeed identical to `Maybe`, but they idea was to reason about the definitions. All comments were very helpful though, and Will Ness's answer more than complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just write it out, following the types:

```
instance Applicative CouldBe where
   {- 
        Minimal complete definition:
          pure, ((<*>) | liftA2)

      pure :: a -> f a 
      pure :: a -> CouldBe a

      liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c 
      liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> CouldBe a -> CouldBe b -> CouldBe c 
   -}
    pure a = fa
        where
        fa = ....

    liftA2 abc fa fb = fc
        where
        fc = ....
```

According to

```
data CouldBe a = Is a | Lost
```

our toolset is

```
Is   :: a -> CouldBe a
Lost :: CouldBe a
```

but we can also use pattern matching, e.g.

```
couldBe   is   lost  (Is a)    = is a
couldBe   is   lost  (Lost)    = lost
couldBe :: ? -> ? -> CouldBe a -> b
couldBe :: ? -> b -> CouldBe a -> b
couldBe :: (a -> b) -> b -> CouldBe a -> b
```

So,

```
    -- pure :: a -> f a 
    pure :: a -> CouldBe a
```

matches up with

```
    Is   :: a -> CouldBe a
```

so we define

```
    pure a = Is a
```

Then, for `liftA2`, we follow the data cases:

```
    -- liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c 
    -- liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> CouldBe a -> CouldBe b -> CouldBe c
    liftA2 abc Lost    _     = ...
    liftA2 abc  _     Lost   = ...
    liftA2 abc (Is a) (Is b) = fc
        where
        c = abc a b
        fc = ....     -- create an `f c` from `c`: 
                      -- do we have a `c -> CouldBe c` ?
                      -- do we have an `a -> CouldBe a` ? (it's the same type)
```

But in the first two cases we don't have an `a` or a `b`; so we have to come up with a `CouldBe c` out of nothing. We do have this tool in *our toolset* as well.

Having completed all the missing pieces, we can substitute the expressions directly into the definitions, eliminating all the unneeded interim values / variables.

Answer (score 1):

With my new [*idiomatic*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/idiomatic) package you can derive `Applicative` for sums.

```
{-# Language DataKinds                #-}
{-# Language DeriveGeneric            #-}
{-# Language DerivingVia              #-}
{-# Language StandaloneKindSignatures #-}

import Data.Kind
import GHC.Generics
import Generic.Applicative

type CouldBe :: Type -> Type
data CouldBe a = Is a | Lost
  deriving
  stock (Eq, Ord, Show, Generic1)

  -- > pure @CouldBe 10
  -- Is 10
  -- > liftA2 (+) (Is 1) Lost
  -- Lost
  -- > liftA2 (+) Lost (Is 10)
  -- Lost
  deriving (Functor, Applicative)
  via Idiomatically CouldBe '[LeftBias Terminal]

-- > tupleCouldBe Lost Lost
-- Lost
-- > tupleCouldBe (Is 1) Lost
-- Lost
-- > tupleCouldBe Lost (Is 20)
-- Lost
-- > tupleCouldBe (Is 1) (Is 20)
-- Is (1,20)
tupleCouldBe :: CouldBe a -> CouldBe b -> CouldBe (a, b)
tupleCouldBe = liftA2 (,)
```

Why does this work? Being left-biased means we choose the `Is` constructor to be the `pure` constructor.

This means we "defect" from that constructor, when lifting over different constructors.

`Terminal` describes how we transform any `Applicative` into `Const mempty`

```hs
data Terminal

instance (Applicative f, Monoid m) => Idiom Terminal f (Const m) where
  idiom :: f ~> Const m
  idiom = mempty
```

which in this case discards the argument of `Is` mapping to `Lost`.

Note there is no way to define a right-biased definition of `CouldBe`, since it would require an applicative morphism that produces an `a` out of nothing

```
  via Idiomatically CouldBe '[RightBias ..]
```

```
  idiom :: Const () ~> Identity
  idiom (Const ()) = Identity ??
```